# Server GUI, problem after installation

Tags: server, gui, vnc, cinnamon, remote

I've recently acquired a small dedicated server from "X" company.
I'm using it for small tasks such as torrenting, ftp, minecraft, etc.

So, I'm trying to install a GUI for my server to browse the web at work (We have a lot of restriction on websites :( )

I read a couple of tutorials, but they all assume I have the server plugged-in right front of me.

I have Ubuntu Server 13.10 installed, I created a new user, lets say, called Anon.
Then, I installed the desktop via `$ apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && cinnamon`

After that, I installed vnc4server to log remotely into the machine; but all I get is a terminal in the vnc viewer. From there, I assume I have to modify a config file to boot into my Desktop Enviroment.

I tried modifying the .vnc/xstartup in my /home directory but I'm still getting my same old terminal window. But now with a cinnamon error :(
( I just added `exec cinnamon-session` to the file)

What I want, is to be able to log in to the server with a VNC viewer and be able to log-out/login as wished to enter different user-sessions etc.

I'm getting comfortable with the command line, but I would also like to have that alternative to browse the web and other stuff.

Thank you for reading, and I tried my best for the grammar (English is my second language!)

Answer (score 0):

Try xrdp. I've found it is the easiest remote desktop server to use. Sudo apt-get install xrdp. Then just log in with any remote desktop client.

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm currently stuck with TigerVnc viewer at work! :(

Comment: This link might be helpful. It doesn't contain instructions specifically for cinnamon but I think the general principle may still apply. http://www.tejasbarot.com/2012/05/17/howto-change-default-user-session-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-login-session-desktop-environment/